# ListBox на UserForm: сортировка, фильтрация, поиск

Tags: excel, объекты, vba

Есть код, который создает листбокс и наполняет его данными с sql запроса. Можно ли сделать как-то так, чтобы данные в этом лист боксе можно было фильтровать, сортировать, искать?

Отправлю скрин того что уже есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно, но без программирования никак.

Comment: спасибо, буду ждать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить параметр  *ListBox* *ColumnHeads=False*. Заголовки можно ставить, если список подгружается с листа по *RowSourse*. При динамическом заполнении заголовки не записываются.

В самом *ListBox* нет возможности сортировки или фильтрации, но можно перезаписывать массив. При сортировке исходный массив можно не хранить - загружать в массив данные из списка, сортировать и после этого выгружать обратно в список. С фильтрацией сложнее - список будет уменьшен, а следующая фильтрация потребует наличия полного списка. Значит, нужно хранить исходный массив данных - на листе, в другом *ListBox*... На листе удобнее - меньше доп. обработок.

С сортировкой можно решить просто: создать на форме контрол для выбора критерия (сортировка по указаному столбцу, вверх, вниз...), при выборе критерия данные сортируются на листе и после этого заносятся в массив.

Для фильтрации и поиска.

Имеем: массив данных на листе в диапазоне столбцов `A:D`; форму с *ListBox* `lbList`. Добавляем на форму *TextBox* с именем `tbWord`. При введении текста в *TextBox* список в *ListBox* будет фильтроваться:

```
Dim aData()

' список в массив'
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With wsList
        aData = .Range("A1:D" & .UsedRange.Rows.count).Value
    End With

    Call ChangeList(False) ' к заполнению ListBox'
End Sub

' при изменении в TextBox - к заполнению ListBox'
Private Sub tbWord_Change(): Call ChangeList(True): End Sub

' заполнение ListBox'
Private Sub ChangeList(ByVal bf As Boolean)
Dim sText As String
Dim i As Long
    With lbList
        .Clear

        Select Case bf
' ---------------------------------------------------------------'
        Case False ' полный список'
            .List = aData
' ---------------------------------------------------------------'
        Case True ' изменение в TextBox'
            If Len(tbWord.Text) = 0 Then ' TextBox пустой, к заполнению полным списком'
                Call ChangeList(False): Exit Sub 
            End If

            sText = UCase$(tbWord.Text) ' искомый текст в верхний регистр'

            For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
                If Len(tbWord.Text) = 1 Then ' если один символ'
                    If UCase$(Left$(aData(i, 2), 1)) = sText Then ' при совпадении добавляем'
                        .AddItem aData(i, 1)
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = aData(i, 2)
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = aData(i, 3)
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = aData(i, 4)
                    End If
                Else ' если символов более одного'
                    If InStr(1, UCase$(aData(i, 2)), sText) > 0 Then 'при совпадении добавляем'
                        .AddItem aData(i, 1)
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = aData(i, 2)
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = aData(i, 3)
                        .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = aData(i, 4)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
' ---------------------------------------------------------------'
        End Select

        .Height = 330 ' высота ListBox
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: все работает, все получилось сделать. спасибо